# Substituir, tag com atributos para mesclagem de documentos

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Olá estou criando um documento que possibilita a mesclagem através de tags, mas, vou permitir que o usuario adicione uma separação dentro da tag, porque estou fazendo isso, no caso de uma qualificação de um cliente meu sistema faria assim

Qualificação tags
||cli_nome||, ||cli_endereco||, ||cli_numero|| - ||cli_complemento||, email: ||cli_email||

Qualificação mesclado considerando que tenha todos os dados
Nome do Cara, Rua Endereço do Cara, 999 - Fundos, email:email@email.com

Qualificação quando esta faltando dados (ex: falta complemento, falta email)
Nome do Cara, Rua Endereço do Cara, 999 -, email:

O que eu faço hj na programação

```
<?php
$texto = "Qualifaicação completa do cliente<br>||cli_nome||, ||cli_endereco, ||cli_numero|| - ||cli_complemento|| email: ||cli_email||.";
$texto = str_replace('||cli_nome||', $rs['nome'], $texto);
$texto = str_replace('||cli_endereco||', $rs['endereco'], $texto);
$texto = str_replace('||cli_numero||', $rs['numero'], $texto);
$texto = str_replace('||cli_complemento||', $rs['complemento'], $texto);
$texto = str_replace('||cli_email||', $rs['email'], $texto);
?>
```

O que eu gostaria de possibilitar o cliente adicionar coisas extras dentro das tags e com um coxetes[] ex:

Qualificação tags
||cli_nome||, ||cli_endereco||||[, ]cli_numero||||[, ]cli_complemento||||[email: ]cli_email||

Existe alguma forma de fazer o replace na tag e se existir o coxete, colocar antes da tag?

Pensando dessa forma ficaria assim:

Qualificação mesclado considerando que tenha todos os dados
Nome do Cara, Rua Endereço do Cara, 999 - Fundos, email:email@email.com

Qualificação quando esta faltando dados (ex: falta complemento, falta email)
Nome do Cara, Rua Endereço do Cara, 999

COMO FAZER ISSO ABAIXO?

```
<?php
$texto = "Qualifaicação completa do cliente<br>||cli_nome||, ||cli_endereco||||[, ]cli_numero||||[ - ]cli_complemento||||[ email:]cli_email||.";
$texto = preg_replace('regx', $rs['cli_nome'], $texto);
$texto = preg_replace('regx', $rs['cli_endereco'], $texto);
$texto = preg_replace('regx', $rs['cli_numero'], $texto);
$texto = preg_replace('regx', $rs['cli_complemento'], $texto);
$texto = preg_replace('regx', $rs['cli_email'], $texto);
?>
```

Obrigado
Marco